# Need to execute test in parallel in spec run

Tags: c#, automation, specflow, specrun

How I can run my automation scripts parallel. My code is in **C#.net** using specflow.

I have changed my unit test provider as below:

```
 <specFlow>
    <!--<unitTestProvider name="MsTest.2010" />-->
    <unitTestProvider name="SpecRun" />
        <plugins>
      <add name="SpecRun" />
    </plugins>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  </specFlow>`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click project in Solution Explorer and regenerate feature files
2. Get .runsettings file from the SpecRun packages folder, copy it, name it, and point your project to it by going to "Test" in the toolbar, and "Test Settings" and "Select Test Settings File"
3. Go to the file for your project "Default.srprofile" and alter the "" attributes to include "testThreadCount=X" where "X" is the number of parallel threads you want executed.